# Change format to object in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have 2 table users and cuti ( in english is PaidLeave) . in table users have a colomn like

> Users : id , name , email , cuti , etc...
>
> Cuti : id , users_id , nama_surat , durasi_cuti , etc

in this store function , i want to decrement this **cuti** on table **Users** ( this cuti is default by 12 (int) )

```
public function store_cuti(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,[
        'berkas' => 'mimes:pdf'
    ] );


    $users = new Data_cuti;
    $users->user_id              = $request->user_id ;
    $users->nama_surat           = $request->nama_surat ;
    $users->tgl_surat            = $request->tgl_surat ;
    $users->durasi_cuti          = $request->durasi_cuti ;
    $users->tgl_mulai            = $request->tgl_mulai ;
    $users->status               = $request->status ;
    $users->berkas               = $data;

    $input = $request->input('durasi_cuti');

    $cuti = DB::table('users')->select('cuti')->where('id',$request->user_id)->first();
        if($request->input('durasi_cuti') > $cuti){
            return 'wrong input';
        }
        elseif($cuti > $request->input('durasi_cuti')){
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->user_id)->update(['cuti' => DB::raw("GREATEST(cuti - $input, 0)")]);

        }
        else{
            return ('error , tidak ada input');
        }

    dd($cuti);
    // $users->save();
    // return redirect ('cuti_pegawai')->with('success', 'Input Succes');


}
```

this problem is this line

```
$cuti = DB::table('users')->select('cuti')->where('id',$request->user_id)->first();
```

if i diedump this i get :

```
    {#480 ▼
  +"cuti": "10"
  }
```

i think its make problem for this line

```
 if($request->input('durasi_cuti') > $cuti)
```

because this value is not object . how to change this ** +"cuti": "10"** to just 10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$cuti` is an object.

so you need to get the field's value by

```
$cuti->cuti
```

Answer (score 1):

You're comparing your condition with an object so that here you may do one thing.

compare with value `$cuti->cuti`

```
$cuti = DB::table('users')->select('cuti')->where('id',$request->user_id)->first();
        if($request->input('durasi_cuti') > $cuti->cuti){
            return 'wrong input';
        }
        elseif($cuti->cuti > $request->input('durasi_cuti')){
            DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->user_id)->update(['cuti' => DB::raw("GREATEST(cuti - $input, 0)")]);

        }
        else{
            return ('error , tidak ada input');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want a single value from a record you can do that with Query Builder using the `value` method:

```
$cuti = DB::table('users')->where('id', $request->user_id)->value('cuti');
```

[Laravel 6.x Docs - Query Builder - Retrieving Results - Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#retrieving-results)